# conditional calculate base on column is not NA in R

Tags: r

I mutate new column `Grade` with calculate existing variables.If group  not NA the take value Divided by Total,

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(value=c(62,71,69,70,66),class=letters[1:5],
                 group = c("A", "C", NA, "A", "B"),
                 Total = c(263, 249, 277, 221, 293))
```

I have tried this way,which obviously doesn't work.

```
df$Grade <- ifelse(is.na(df$group), NA, df$value[!is.na(df$group)]/Total)
```

Here is my desired output

```
  value class group Total   Grade
1    62     a     A   263   0.235
2    71     b     C   249   0.285
3    69     c  <NA>   277      NA
4    70     d     A   221   0.316
5    66     e     B   293   0.225
```

Any tips is helpful.

Comment: `df$Grade <- ifelse(is.na(df$group), NA, df$value/df$Total)`

Comment: @Jon Spring, thank you for answer, if I want to using pipe ```%>%``` , how can I reedit?

Comment: ```df %>%  mutate(Grade = ifelse(is.na(group), NA, value/Total))```

Comment: @mashimena no worries. You can also do it like this in `dplyr`: ```df %>% mutate(Grade = na_if(!is.na(group), 0) * (value / Total))```